# Javascript new Date("2023-11-1") does not give a date starting at the start of the day but new Date("2023/11/01") does

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

```js
console.log(new Date("2023-11-01"))
# Date Wed Nov 01 2023 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 11, 1)))
# Date Wed Nov 01 2023 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date("2023/11/01"))
# Date Wed Nov 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(2023, 11, 1))
# Date Wed Nov 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date("November 1, 2023"))
# Date Wed Nov 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

These seem to be some more JS quirks I didn't knew about. Or are there good reasons for these glaring inconsistencies?

Firefox version: `119.0.1 (64-bit)`

OS: `Ubuntu 22.04`

Comment: use `.toUTCString()` instead of `.toString()` if you want to work with formats using UTC

Comment: Probably JS treats first format as ISO 8601, and without explicitly setting timezone it uses UTC as default. Where with more lax formats it uses local timezone as default.

Comment: Your second and fourth examples should actually be outputting Dec 1 since  months are 0 indexed when using that form

Comment: Also covered in the docs, here from [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#using_date.parse): *'Implementations usually default to the local time zone when the date string is non-standard'* **vs** date only ISO 8601 strings which *'will imply UTC time because it's date-only'*

Comment: "2023-11-01" is parsed as UTC. Parsing of "2023/11/01" is implementation dependent and may produce an invalid date or one based on the local (host system) offset, e.g. "Wed Nov 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Chamorro Standard Time)".